# Is it possible to set multiple font attributes using an NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, string, nsattributedstring

I am trying to decrease the size of a portion of my string and am using the below code.  My output is not correct.  I am only seeing my first font attribute being used for the entire string, not the specified range.

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title];
    NSInteger _stringLength=[descriptionText length];
    [attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                      value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Bold" size:20.0]
                      range:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
    [attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                      value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0]
                      range:NSMakeRange(11, _stringLength-1)];
    [self.description setAttributedText:attString];
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're initting your string with `title` but you're using the length of `descriptionText`?

Comment: They're interchangeable, but i should use one or the other. I pass descriptionText to the method, local method variable is title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Possibly you are trying to use font names that don't exist. Did you check that the fonts actually exist, e.g. by po or NSLog?

What's the output if you log the attributedString?

Answer (score 6):

I've had this issue too. For the second font selection you need to set the minus on the string length to be the same as where it starts.

```
  [attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                    value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0]
                    range:NSMakeRange(11, _stringLength-11)];
```

rather than:

```
  [attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                    value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0]
                    range:NSMakeRange(11, _stringLength-1)];
```

Answer (score 4):

My 2 cents ;) Swift 3

```
func attributedTexts(text1: String, attribs1: [String : Any]?, text2: String, attribs2: [String : Any]?) {

    let str = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text1, attributes: attribs1);
    str.append(NSAttributedString(string: text2, attributes: attribs2))

    return str
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let attr1 = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24)]
let attr2 = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)]
let attributedString = self.attributedTexts(text1: "First Text", attribs1: attr1, text2: "\nSecond Text", attribs2: attr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this site and video, you may get something usefull

[Rich text](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/rich-text-editing-on-ios/)